# How to get string block starting a pattern in awk

Tags: awk

I just need to make a insert.sql file which includes 'INSERT' statements in A file. Can you help me learn how to handle the string block with a AWK?

@ INPUT FILE

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET CO1 = '11111', COL2 = '234234234'
WHERE COL3 < SYSDATE;

UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET CO1 = '11111', COL2 = '234234234'
WHERE COL3 < SYSDATE;

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) 
VALUES('ASKDFJ','ASKDJFL',SYSDATE);

UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET CO1 = '11111', COL2 = '234234234'
WHERE COL3 < SYSDATE;

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) 
VALUES('ASKDFJ','ASKDJFL',SYSDATE-2);
```

@ OUTPUT

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) 
VALUES('ASKDFJ','ASKDJFL',SYSDATE);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3) 
VALUES('ASKDFJ','ASKDJFL',SYSDATE-2);
```

Comment: You want to remove `UPDATE` statements? And what is a *"string block"* please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print what is between `INSERT` and an empty line:

```
$ awk '/INSERT/,/^$/' file
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3)
VALUES('ASKDFJ','ASKDJFL',SYSDATE);

INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(COL1,COL2,COL3)
VALUES('ASKDFJ','ASKDJFL',SYSDATE-2);
```

Choose the `INSERT` and empty line regexps to your liking.

Comment: Very simple but pretty useful though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n'  '$0 ~ "^INSERT"' file
```

The record separator `RS` is set to 2 newlines.

`$0 ~ "^INSERT"` prints the record that starts with the keyword `INSERT`

Comment: Probably better to set RS to the empty string.

Comment: Yes, better to set RS with empty strings. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v ORS="\n" -v RS= '/^INSERT/{print $0}' inputfile
```